# Send ZIP file from vb6 to web service SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, vb6

I have the following code developed in Visual Basic 6.0 (vb6) in which already managed to connect to the web service, but when I send the ZIP file into a byte array returns me an error telling me that the ZIP file is corrupt, obviously I'm not sending ZIP file correctly and that is the reason for the error.

Below the code I use.

```
Dim strFileName2 As String
Dim nFile As Integer
Dim strImage As String
Dim strBoundary As String
Dim AsmxUrl As String
Dim SoapActionUrl As String
Dim filebytes() As Byte
Dim Attachment() As Byte

SoapActionUrl = "https://www.sat.gob.mx/ol-ti-itcpgem-beta/billService"
AsmxUrl = "https://www.sat.gob.mx/ol-ti-itcpgem-beta/billService?wsdl"
strBoundary = "----=_Part_23_1578679283.1448552263862"
strFileName2 = "C:\20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip"
nFile = FreeFile()

Dim adostream As Object
adostream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adostream.Open()
adostream.Type = 1
adostream.LoadFromFile strFileName2
filebytes = adostream.Read
adostream.Close()

Open strFileName2 For Binary As #nFile
strImage = String(LOF(nFile), " ")
Get #nFile, , strImage
Close #nFile

'message head SOAP
Xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' " & _
            "xmlns:ser='http://service.sat.gob.mx' " & _
            "xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'> " & _
            "   <soapenv:Header>      " & _
            "       <wsse:Security>         " & _
            "           <wsse:UsernameToken>           " & _
            "               <wsse:Username>USUSARIO</wsse:Username>            " & _
            "               <wsse:Password>CONTRASENA</wsse:Password> " & _
            "           </wsse:UsernameToken>      " & _
            "       </wsse:Security>   " & _
            "   </soapenv:Header> " & _
            "   <soapenv:Body> " & _
            "       <ser:sendBill> " & _
            "               <!--Optional:--> " & _
            "               <fileName>20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip</fileName> " & _
            "               <!--Optional:--> " & _
            "               <contentFile><inc:Include href=""cid:20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip"" xmlns:inc=""http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include""/></contentFile>" & _
            "       </ser:sendBill> " & _
            "   </soapenv:Body> " & _
            "</soapenv:Envelope> "

'"               <contentFile>cid:20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip</contentFile> " & _
'message attachment
Attachment = filebytes

'multipart message template
SendDataS = "--$boundary$" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=""text/xml""" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>" & Chr(10) & _
            "" & Chr(10) & _
            "$xml$" & Chr(10) & _
            "--$boundary$" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-Type: application/zip; name=20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-ID: <20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip>" & Chr(10) & _
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=""20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip""; filename=""20502264096-01-F001-9672.zip""" & Chr(10) & _
            " " & Chr(10) & _
            "$Attachment$" & Chr(10) & _
            "--$boundary$" & "--"

'Create objects to DOMDocument and XMLHTTP
objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

strXmlHead = ""
strXmlBody = ""


'Load XMLHead
objDom.async = False
objDom.LoadXml Xml 'aqui carga el XML armado antes
strXmlHead = objDom.xml 'aqui lee el XML

MsgBox(objDom.xml)

'Load XMLbody
'objDom.async = False
'objDom.LoadXml Attachment

MsgBox(Attachment)

'strXmlBody = objDom.LoadXml
strXmlBody = Attachment

strXml = Replace(SendDataS, "$xml$", strXmlHead)
strXml = Replace(strXml, "$Attachment$", strXmlBody)
strXml = Replace(strXml, "$boundary$", strBoundary)

MsgBox(strXml)
Me.Text1.Text = strXml
'Open the webservice
objXmlHttp.Open("POST", AsmxUrl, False)

'Create headings
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0")
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=""" & strBoundary & """")

objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*")
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", """" & SoapActionUrl & """")
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", Len(strXml))
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Close")

'Send XML command
objXmlHttp.send CStr(strXml) 'objDom.xml

'Get all response text from webservice
strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText
MsgBox(strRet)
```

Comment: I´m not sure, but shouldn´t you read a byte array instead of string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for posting to web server. Maybe you can get something for you...

```
Private Function mbPostFile(sRequest As String, sFileName As String, sExpectedNode As String, ByRef oNode As IXMLDOMNode) As Boolean
  Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"

  Dim sPostData       As String
  Dim oStream         As Object

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  If Not mbCheckSession Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
  oStream.Type = 1 'binary
  Call oStream.Open
  Call oStream.LoadFromFile(sFileName)

  sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    StrConv(oStream.Read, vbUnicode) & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"

  With moGetHttp
    Call .Open("POST", msPortalUrl & sRequest & "&session=" & msSession, False)
    Call .setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY)
    Call .send(pvToByteArray(sPostData))

    mbPostFile = mbCheckResult(.responseXML, sExpectedNode, oNode, True)
  End With

  Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
  Call mShowError("mbPostFile")
End Function

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
  pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but even I have problems :(